# CsvHelper isn't parsing csv

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm trying to use [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/reading#getting-all-records) to parse a csv file and get an array of class objects. But I can't get any results from CsvReader. What am I doing wrong?

```
TextReader reader = File.OpenText("test.csv");
string stringResult=reader.ReadToEnd(); //this works

var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
TestCsvEntity[] resultReader = csvReader.GetRecords<TestCsvEntity>().ToArray(); //but this is empty
```

My test.csv file is just this:

```
RowNumber,Value
1,a
2,b
3,c
```

And my class object is

```
public class TestCsvEntity
{
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing `reader.ReadToEnd()` AND `GetRecords<>()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in your code, remove it:

```
string stringResult=reader.ReadToEnd(); //this works
```

It is likely reading to the end of the stream and then you are passing a reader to the CSVHelper that is at the last position in the stream.  You want to pass CSVHelper a stream that is at the start position.

Try this for debugging:

```
TextReader reader = File.OpenText("test.csv");

Console.WriteLine("Stream Length:" + reader.BaseStream.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Stream Position before ReadToEnd(): " + reader.BaseStream.Position);

string stringResult=reader.ReadToEnd(); //this works

Console.WriteLine("Stream Position after ReadToEnd(): " + reader.BaseStream.Position);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was having a different error, added the `stringResult` to see if it was reading the file at all, didn't realize that was introducing a second error. Out of curiosity is it possible to move the reader back to the start position? Or would I use a new stringreader?

Comment: @Matthew, yes if it supports 'seeking' you can set the position to zero.  if(stream.CanSeek) stream.Position = 0; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position(v=vs.110).aspx